# C++ function which is only enabled if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I think I just made a C++ paradox...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// If has_f trait is defined in this way, compilation breaks because of infinite recursion in template substitution
/*
template< typename T, typename Enable=void >
struct has_f : std::false_type { };

template< typename T >
struct has_f<T, decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))> : std::true_type { };
*/

// Defining has_f like this works on MSVC, gcc and CLang
namespace has_f_impl {
  struct no{ };
  template< typename T >
  no check(...);
  template< typename T >
  decltype(f(std::declval<T>())) check(void const*);

  template< typename T >
  struct has_f : std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same<no, decltype(check<T>(nullptr))>::value> { };
}
using has_f_impl::has_f;

struct Foo { };
struct Bar { };

template< typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Foo, T>::value, int> = 0 >
void f(T const&);

template< typename T, std::enable_if_t<!has_f<T const&>::value, int> = 1 >
void f(T const&);

int main() {
  f(Foo()); // Calls f<Foo,0>()
  f(Bar()); // Calls f<Bar,1>()
  f(Foo()); // Calls f<Foo,0>()
  f(Bar()); // Calls f<Bar,1>()
}
```

The above code surprisingly works, and in a very smart way, only using the generic `f` when there's really no other option.

Also, and this is probably because of ODR, the following happens

```
// Includes, has_f, Foo, Bar and f as above
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t<has_f<T const&>::value>* = nullptr >
void g(T const&);

int main() {
  f(Foo()); // Calls f<Foo,0>()
  f(Bar()); // Calls f<Bar,1>()
  f(Foo()); // Calls f<Foo,0>()
  f(Bar()); // Calls f<Bar,1>()
  g(Foo());
  //g(Bar()); //No such function
}
```

As far as I tried, all of this seems to be independent from declaration order.

My question is: what's really happening here? Is this a standard-defined behavior, an undefined condition which all the compiler I tried handle in the same way, or a bug which is present by coincidence in all the compilers I tried?

Comment: templates are not expanded until they are used. declaration order is therefore unimportant.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Template functions are still sensitive to declaration order if they call functions which don't depend on dependent types or member functions on non-dependent types. gcc's error about that is quite clear here: https://ideone.com/lQq9AS It was just to say thay I tried changing the order around, anyway, regardless of whether it's important or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is all simply covered by [[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#14):

> The result of an infinite recursion in instantiation is
>   undefined.

Regardless of which way you define your `has_f`, it involves infinite recursion. `has_f<Bar>` involves the instantiation of `f(Bar )` which involves the instantiation of `has_f<Bar>` which involves the instantiation of ...

The fact that one way of defining `has_f` works in some circumstances but not in others, and the other way definitely doesn't work, is just a consequence of undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: I'm not marking this as accepted yet, just because I want to be completely sure that there's in fact an infinite recursion here, and not some other black magic by which that evaluation becomes non infinitely recursive. But I'm positive it's just as you said. Would still be nice to understand what happens, but maybe I need to ask some compiler developer for that.

Comment: It might be possible to reject this code on the points of instantiation of the declarations of `check`, infinite recursion or not.

Comment: @T.C. what do you mean?